# Having trouble getting my MouseListener to work for a Pokemon game for high school

Tags: java, swing, awt, mouselistener

I have a class for the game where most of the rendering and framework is done. I have a class for the mouse listener. I also have a class called Menu that draws a menu on the canvas. I want it to actually start the game when I click on the "Start" button but it seems as though the MouseListener is not receiving the mouse click.

I have tried putting the line `addMouseListener(new MouseInput())` in many places throughout the Game class but it will not work.

```
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseListener;

public class MouseInput implements MouseListener
{

    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) 
    {
    int mx = e.getX();
    int my = e.getY();
        if(Game.STATE == 0)
        {
            if(mx >= 415 && mx <= 615)
            {
                if(my >= 350 && my <= 425)  
                {
                    Game.STATE = Game.STATE + 1;
                }
            }

            if(mx >= 415 && mx <=615)
            {
                if(my >= 500 && my <= 575)
                {
                    System.exit(1);
                }

            }
        }
    }
}
```

//Game Class

```
public class Game extends JFrame implements Runnable
{

    private Canvas c = new Canvas();
    public static int STATE = 0;
    public static final int WIDTH = 1000;
    public static final int HEIGHT = 800;
    private Menu menu;
    private FightState fight;



    public Game()
    {
        //Forces program to close when panel is closed
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        //sets position and size of Frame
        setBounds(0, 0, WIDTH, HEIGHT);

        //puts Frame in center of the screen
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);

        //adds canvas to game
        add(c);

        //Makes frame visible
        setVisible(true);

        //creates our object for buffer strategy
        c.createBufferStrategy(2);

//      adds the mouse listner;
        addMouseListener(new MouseInput());



    }


    public void update()
    {

    }

    //renders the graphics onto the screen
    public void render()
    {
        BufferStrategy bufferStrategy = c.getBufferStrategy();
        Graphics g = bufferStrategy.getDrawGraphics();
        super.paint(g);


        //instantiates the menu object
        menu = new Menu();
        //instantiates the FightState object
        fight = new FightState();

        //renders the menu
            if(STATE == 0)
            {
                menu.render(g);
            }
        //renders the fight stage
            if(STATE == 1)
            {
                fight.render(g);
            }   

            g.setFont(new Font("Monospaced", Font.PLAIN, 35));
            g.drawString("STATE: " + STATE, 10, 400);
            repaint();

            //checks if mouseListener is working
            System.out.print(STATE);

            g.dispose();
            bufferStrategy.show();

    }

    //game loop
    public void run()
    {
        BufferStrategy bufferStrategy = c.getBufferStrategy();

        long lastTime = System.nanoTime(); //long is an int that stores more space
        double nanoSecondConvert = 1000000000.0 / 60; //frames/sec
        double deltaSeconds = 0;




        while(true)
        {
            long now = System.nanoTime();

            deltaSeconds += (now-lastTime)/nanoSecondConvert;

            while(deltaSeconds >=1)
            {
                update();
                deltaSeconds = 0;
            }

            render();
            lastTime = now;
            System.out.println("STATE: " + STATE);
        }

    }


    //main method
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Game game = new Game();
        Thread gameThread = new Thread(game);
        gameThread.start();
    }
}
```

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, [edit] to add a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). 2) Please use code formatting for code and code snippets, structured documents like HTML/XML or input/output.  To do that, select the text and click the `{}` button at the top of the message posting/editing form. 3) A single blank line of white space in source code is all that is *ever* needed.  Blank lines after `{` or before `}` are also typically redundant.

Answer (score 0):

Don't call `super.paint(g);` on the `JFrame` if you're using a `BufferStrategy`.  Just paint to the buffer directly. You should also be adding your `MouseListener` to the `Canvas`, not the frame.

The `Canvas` is laid out WITHIN the frame boundaries of the window, meaning it will be offset and smaller than the actual frame itself.

Mouse events are automatically converted to the sources coordinate context, this means, you are currently trying to compare values coming from the frame's coordinate context with values been used by the `Canvas` which are different

> One question: How would i paint directly to the buffer if buffer doesnt have the "Graphics methods" such as fillRect()?

`Graphics g = bufferStrategy.getDrawGraphics()` gives you the `Graphics` context, you then paint directly to it.

You don’t want to call `paint` directly (ever) as it can be called by the system and you could up with race conditions and other issues

Swing uses a different painting algorithm, which you've opted out of by using a `BufferStrategy`, this means you can no longer make use of the "normal" Swing painting process and instead, must write your own

Comment: Thank you so much this really helped. One question: How would i paint directly to the buffer if buffer doesnt have the "Graphics methods" such as fillRect()?

Comment: `Graphics g = bufferStrategy.getDrawGraphics();` gives you the `Graphics` context, you then paint directly to it. You don’t want to call `paint` directly (ever) as it can be called by the system and you could up with race conditions and other issues